# Remover uma propriedade de um objeto contido numa array

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma variavel array:

```
Bola = [];
```

Adicionei as propriedades a ela:

```
Bola[0] = { peso:0.5, cor:"branca", marca:"nike", nota:8 };
Bola[1] = { peso:0.7, cor:"verde", marca:"adidas", nota:9  };
```

Gostaria de remover as propriedades "marca" e "peso". Como faço isso?

Comment: delete Bola[0].peso ?

Comment: nem sabia da existencia desse delete!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) para remover propriedades dos objetos dentro da array (que é o que você tem, dois objetos dentro da array `bola`.

```js
// Não esqueça o var!
var bola = [];
bola[0] = { peso:0.5, cor:"branca", marca:"nike", nota:8 };
bola[1] = { peso:0.7, cor:"verde", marca:"adidas", nota:9  };

for(var i=0; i<bola.length; i++) {
    delete bola[i].marca;
    delete bola[i].peso;
}
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(bola);
```

Nota: use minúsculas para nomear variáveis, deixe as iniciais maiúsculas para "classes" (funções construtoras).

Answer (score -3):

Atualmente existe uma alternativa para fazer o mesmo!

```js
// Para arrays usa palavra no plural!
const bolas = [];
bolas[0] = { peso:0.5, cor:"branca", marca:"nike", nota:8 };
bolas[1] = { peso:0.7, cor:"verde", marca:"adidas", nota:9  };

const novasBolas = bolas.map(bola => ({
  peso: bola.peso,
  cor: bola.cor
})
```

No exemplo acima, essa função map é parecida com o forEach, mas ela retorna um array novo.

1. Para cada elemento eu faço uma operação.
2. Na operação eu faço um retorno implicito de um objeto.
3. No objeto de retorno eu passo somente os valores que eu quero usar.

Comment: Olá Arthur. Legal você ter interesse em participar, mas preciso dizer, eu não diria que `Array.map()` é melhor, na verdade é ao contrário, é pior, as operações internas ficam mais custosas. Claro que em um array pequeno não se nota isso.

Comment: O meu -1 é pelo fato de dizer que é uma forma melhor, o que é um engano bem sério. Acho legal mostrar como alternativa, mas teria que tirar o erro para eu poder positivar. Lembrando que como parte da filosofia do site, toda postagem pode ser editada para se melhorar ou corrigir, e todo voto pode ser revisado após uma edição. Note, eu acho que se tirar a parte opinativa, realmente ficará uma ótima resposta pra complementar.

Comment: Entendido, muito obrigado pelos feedbacks, serve como aprendizado!